# Recover the bitcoin using my bank account transaction details

Tags: wallet-recovery

I lost my wallet and i purchased using my internet banking and Is there possible way to recover my bitcoin using my bank account transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin has no relation to the banking network - if you're lucky, you might have purchased BTC on a custodial platform (one which keeps the private keys for you) and your bank account's transaction history can help you identify which platform you had sent funds to. You should then be able to contact their support to regain access to your account.

If you moved the BTC to a wallet where you maintain the private keys and have lost access to that, you are out of luck unless you made a backup.

If someone asked you to transfer them fiat through the banking system, promising Bitcoin or high investment returns in exchange, you may have been scammed.

Comment: i have purchased very long back at that time i spent 1 coin = 1 Indian rupees but due to the job movement to different location i forgot my wallet

Comment: Bitcoin price has never been 1 BTC = 1 INR at any point where India actually had exchanges you could transfer to - you've likely been scammed if that's actually what happened